Is methodological naturalism a bias/axiom of science or a conclusion of it?
In this article here, Richard Carrier makes the interesting argument that methodological naturalism is a result of what we have encountered in the world through experience and not due to an axiomatic bias towards naturalism. His main line of argument in the article is that because we have never established supernatural entities as the cause of anything, we, as a result of this lack of evidence, decided to not use them in science.
However, as per the SEP article here,

In this sense, “methodological naturalism” is the view that religious commitments have no relevance within science: natural science itself requires no specific attitude to religion, and can be practised just as well by adherents of religious faiths as by atheists or agnostics (Draper 2005).

When framed this way, it seems to imply that this method is purely based on the idea that one does not need religious concepts to do science.
But the question is this: is the lack of a need for religious concepts in science a result of the lack of evidence of religious concepts operating in the world, or due to a mere apriori preference or bias for avoiding religious talk in science?

If we had encountered supernatural entities, we would probably be classifying them as part of nature.

Religion is a silly word. Methodological naturalism indeed requires no specific attitude towards the stuff that is superficially similar to what Christians do when they're doing Christian worship as opposed to Christian non-worship.

He's mistaken. Many people have explained supernatural entities as the cause of things. He rejects those explanations because of a bias towards naturalism. The fact that he doesn't recognize this suggests he's not cut out for philosophical thinking.

@DavidGudeman How do you differentiate between him being “biased” for naturalism and not being “cut out for philosophical thinking” and supernatural entities just failing to be a good explanation?

It can be really hard to separate cause and effect in how an argument is constructed. Humans are just very bad at reasoning, despite trying for thousands of years. But, planes fly (and submarines swim).

@ScottRowe, if you couldn't explain a cause without explaining the cause of the cause, then you could never explain anything.

@ScottRowe, how is that a "solution"? If you can't explain something without presenting an infinite chain of explanations, then logically you can never explain anything.

@DavidGudeman this is true but in every case of a valid causal explanation, we already know that the cause exists and can atleast construct a coherent, plausible story that leads from cause to effect. This works even if we don’t know the cause of that cause. The problem is that we don’t know if god exists and thus cannot construct this story. Hence, it serves as a weak explanation not because of a bias but as a result of its lack of explanatory power. If you believe that it is a good explanation, can you give full steps of an explanation that leads from God to literally anything?

@Syed, so you don't think electrons and atoms are valid causal explanations? Because no one knew that they existed before postulating them as a cause. And there is nothing implausible about the idea of a supernatural explanation. All you are doing is expressing your own prejudices.

@DavidGudeman we have a coherent story that goes from posits such as atoms to various features of the world. As questioned earlier, can you do this with god that doesn’t amount to “god wanted this” or “god did it”?

@Syed, no you don't. There are many important things that you have no way to explain that way, and even the things you do explain always come down in the end to "that's just the way things work". You can no more explain why opposite charges attract than I can explain anything God does. You are engaging in positive reinforcement. You subject my beliefs to the most severe analysis and criticism while treating your own beliefs as so obvious that they needn't be examined.

There are multiple philosophic essays and papers on just this question, and several well recognized categories of answer.  This question is therefore asking for what SE considers a "good subjective" answer, and should never have been closed:  https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

A short answer can be summarized here:  science makes no presumptions about ontology or religion, and is to follow evidence wherever it goes.  If that evidence points to or away from a religion, both are possible outcomes of the methodology.  Methodological naturalism is just empiricism assisted by reasoning, used to derive indirect realism.  It is a method of doing epistemology, and is contrasted with rationalism, where reality is determined by reason alone, and intuitionism, where reality can be directly intuited.  Religions often assert intuitionalism as an alternate epistemology.

@causative -- is this a topic you agree should not have been closed?  We are at 4 reopen votes.

Voted to reopen, because this is a perfectly fine question. A strong, convincing answer can be found in Collingwood's Essay on Metaphysics.

It's... both, kind of.
Methodological naturalism is somewhat of an annoying label, because it can be misinterpreted as an upfront exclusion of any possibility of any "supernatural" entity, which isn't what science does.
Methodological naturalism means building models from empirical data without starting from any presuppositions about "supernatural" entities that we have no direct empirical evidence for.
If, from empirical evidence, we were to see the effects of some entity we can't directly observe, we could still conclude that such an entity exists.
This would be similarly applicable to:

determining that there was a murderer if we find a dead body with a bunch of stab wounds
determining that there was some entity with no directly-detectable body that acted in some way in the physical world

Although some key differences are that for a murderer, we already know that humans exist, we already know that murders are a thing that happens, and that humans are murderers, we know how to identify murders (compared to death by natural causes or non-death), we can directly observe the person who did the murder if we find them, etc.
So by comparison, one certainly needs much stronger evidence before it's reasonable to conclude that some not-directly-detectable entity did something. But it's certainly theoretically possible to reach such a conclusion using methodological naturalism.
The fact that we can't reasonably reach conclusions about such entities through empirical evidence is one of the best reasons to reject claims of such entities (at least until such a time when the existence of such entities can be concluded from the evidence). As for claims of the existence of entities that don't interact with the observable world at all, one might reject those due to Occam's razor - by definition, they explain no evidence (there are logical arguments to try to conclude their existence, but those are dubious).

Note: The term "methodological naturalism" was apparently coined in 1983. That's a really, really long time after we humans first came about, and a fairly long time after we started robustly investigating the world via science.
So one might say the term itself came about from the fact that proposed gods and such did not interact with the world in an identifiable and reliably observable way. This was despite many believers in such entities having spent excessive amounts of time looking for empirical evidence of what those entities might've done or supposedly did. So this conclusion is partially incorporated into that.
Science didn't change in 1983 when the term was coined. Rather, this was just recognising that we shouldn't just assume things when we do science, and more specifically that we shouldn't just assume the existence of gods and such.
